# How do I setup a recurring Skype meeting?

Tags: skype, calendar, meetings

I would like to setup a recurring meeting using Skype. I tried to Google it but only received a closed question from Superuser with no answers([here](https://www.google.com/search?q=skype%20recurring%20meeting&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)).

Comment: Great question. I bet this could be useful to many.

Answer (score 1):

If creating the meeting in outlook, yes for skype, go to calendars. If you have skype installed on your computer, click New Skype Meeting in the ribbon. A new window will open up as an email. In the ribbon of that window is a selection named "Recurrence". If you click that, a window will appear, with all the options you are looking for.

Enjoy